# Add or remove a datepicker from a textfield according to selected dropdown value

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a form used to search data.  On that form I have a `textbox`, a `dropdown list`, and a search `button`.  In my `dropdown`, I have options:

- check in date
- last name
- reservation id

I want to add a `datepicker` to the `textbox`, but only when "check in date" has been selected.

Once the `datepicker` is added to the `textbox` - I can't remove it. How can I remove the `datepicker` when the other options have been selected?

This is my `jquery`

```
$('#list').change(function() {
  var selected = $(this).val();

  if(selected == 2) {
    $('#text').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
  } else {
    $('#text').prev().val(''); //here , need to remove the date picker 
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok when the another option is selected you can use the `.datepicker( "destroy" )` function to remove it.

example:

```
if(selected == 2) {
    $('#text').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
  } else {
    $('#text').prev().val('');

    // first test if it exist...example you can set a property then if true destroy it.
    $('#text').datepicker("destroy");
  }
```